# Excel Evaluate() with INDEX(range, ROW(), 1) uses wrong row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to write a My_Eval function (Performing calculations where I look up functions in a table).

This is my VBA

```
Function MY_EVAL(ref as String) As Variant
    MY_EVAL = evaluate(ref)
End Function
```

Which should work, here is where it fails.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TOP | Cell 2 | `=MY_EVAL(B3)` |
| 2 | BOTTOM | Cell 4 | `=MY_EVAL(B3)` |
| 3 | Formula | INDEX(A:B,ROW(),1) |  |

C1 Shows TOP, as expected

C2 Shows TOP as well instead of BOTTOM, Why?

Performing `My_Eval` on cell containing `Row()` also works as expected.

I expected for cell C to evaluate to BOTTOM, instead of evaluating to "TOP"

Comment: Can you show us your function exactly as entered into C1 and C2?

Comment: Sorry, stack overflow didn't like "=MY_EVAL(B3)"...

My exact formula is "=MY_EVAL(B3)" Do you mean what the exact argument is goign to MY_EVAL?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for pointing that out. (I counted the rows as a Programmer rather than excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function may produce unexpected results if the sheet with your lookup table is not the ActiveSheet - the default `Application.Evaluate` uses the ActiveSheet for context: if you want to use a specific sheet then use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` form.

For example:

```vb
Function MY_EVAL(ref As String) As Variant
    MY_EVAL = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Evaluate(ref)
End Function
```

(Using `ThisCell` to identify the cell with the formula calling this function)

**EDIT**: this still doesn't work - info from here https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-using-column-or-row-within-evaluate.802692/

> "The COLUMN function returns an array that apparently Evaluate can't
> dereference."

Same applies to `ROW()` - if you put in your UDF:

`Debug.Print TypeName(Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Evaluate("ROW()"))`

it will give you `Variant()` which explains the problem.

So using @scottcraner's suggestion below:

```vb
Function MY_EVAL(ref As String) As Variant
    With Application.ThisCell
        MY_EVAL = .Worksheet.Evaluate(Replace(ref, "ROW()", .Row))
    End With
End Function
```

...assuming `ref` doesn't use forms like (eg) `ROW(A1:A3)` etc.

Comment: Did you test this out? That does solve an issue I had where it would use the active sheet... However it, it still suffers from the same problem... It does not evaluate ROW() correctly.

Comment: You're correct - I was focused on the worksheet issue.  See edit above.

Comment: So something like this: `.Evaluate(Replace(Replace(ref, "ROW()", Application.ThisCell.Row), "COLUMN()", Application.ThisCell.Column))` may be a work around?

Comment: Thank you! This works as a solution.

I am not sure I agree with their conclusion for why Evaluate fails with  ROW() as Evaluate("ROW()") gives you the expected value, it's only when combound with other things that it fails..