# Use Excel VBA Evaluate Method to Return/Analyze Moving Array At Every Row Over Range

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

The VBA evaluate method can be tricky for array formulas in that many Excel functions don't natively accept arrays as arguments, but it is very useful as it speeds up processing time over loops or spreadsheet formulas by orders of magnitude. For example, I've automated the alignment of signals (several hundred thousand rows) captured by separate data loggers with the use of the EVALUATE("INDEX(IF(1,N(OFFSET(...)") idiom over several columns to resample and ultimately do a correlation sweep across the signals. Doing this with VBA Evaluate takes seconds rather than the hours it took to fill down, then calculate the formulas, then manually move data around...

I am now trying to use the Evaluate method over a large range of data to speed up a peak finding algorithm. The problem I'm having is that, with both VBA Evaluate and spilling array formulas directly in the spreadsheet, only the first calculated value or overall max is returned for each row in the range. I believe this is similar to many other questions I've read on how to use Evaluate, but I can't figure out how to apply the solutions to my case.

The attached image shows an example of what I'm basically trying to accomplish using a random signal in column B and spreadsheet formulas filled down through the range in columns C and D. In the example, I have identified if each sample in the signal is a local peak over a +/-100 ms (i.e., 5 sample) range. I included two different formulas in columns C and D to identify the peaks to illustrate multiple generic approaches:

Filled down in Column C: "= B3 = MAX(OFFSET(B$1,ROW()-3,0,5))"
Filled down in Column D: "= B3 = MAX(FILTER(B$3:B$51,(ROW(B$3:B$51)>=ROW() - 2)*(ROW(B$3:B$51)<=ROW()+2)))"

Sample Peak Detection

[image: 1]

I can't recall all the variations I've tried to get this to work with a single Evaluate operation in VBA, but following is a small sample. As with the generic example in the image above, assume the signal data is in column B and we're identifying peaks in column C. Rather than explicitly identifying whether a sample is a peak, the formulas below are simply trying to return the peak for +/- 2 samples from each row.

```
Sub EvalXmpl()

Dim LR as Long 'Last row

LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets(1)

  ' Example 1 - Returns MAX of overall range for every row
  .Range("C3:C" & LR) = .Evaluate("INDEX(IF(1,MAX(N(OFFSET(B1,ROW(C3:C" & LR & ") - 3,0,5)))),)")

  ' Example 2 - Returns MAX of overall range for every row
'  .Range("C3:C" & LR) = .Evaluate("IF(ROW(3:" & LR & "),MAX(N(OFFSET(B1,ROW(3:" & LR & ") - 3,0,5))))")

  ' Example 3 - Returns MAX of first calculation for every row
'  .Range("C3:C" & LR) = .Evaluate("INDEX(IF(1,MAX(FILTER(B3:B" & LR & ",(ROW(3:" & LR & _
      ") >= ROW()-2)*(ROW(3:" & LR & ") <= ROW()+2)))),)")

End With

End Sub
```

I tried variations on all of those to see if I could force the arrays to return correctly. There are two things I think may be hanging me up

1. Forcing an array formula via INDEX() or IF(ROW()) when Evaluate returns a single value for each row works fine, but since I'm returning a moving range at each row forcing isn't working the same.
2. MAX natively accepts an array so it's somehow negating the forcing?

Some resources

- https://exceljet.net/formulas/return-array-with-index-function
- https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/use-evaluate-in-vba-instead-of-looping-through-cells/
- https://newtonexcelbach.com/tag/evaluate/

Comment: Related to use of `ROW()` or `COLUMN()` in an `Evaluate`d formula: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74351253/478884  Also: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/#:~:text=Using%20Evaluate%20INDEX(rng%2Crownum%2CCOLUMN())%20gives%20incorrect%20answers%20except%20for%20the%20first%20column

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams. I had read that thread and it helped with previous problems. I know that ROW() does not evaluate correctly and left out that point as I felt my question was getting too long. Did not include an example where I used a helper column with row numbers and OFFSET in place of ROW().

Comment: Use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from Excel or use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Is a markdown table a more preferred format for example data than an image like I attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Running Peaks

**Hardcoded**

```vb
Sub RunningPeaks()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        With .Range("B3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            .EntireRow.Columns("C").Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate( _
                "BYROW(" & .Address & ",LAMBDA(r,r=MAX(OFFSET(r,-2,0,5))))")
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually just discovered BYROW yesterday and only halfheartedly attempted to apply it to my problem. Works beautifully. May I ask about the formatting of your code? Is there a reason you use .EntireRow.Columns as the range in which to apply the formula?

Comment: Readability, flexibility... (once you get used to it) Let's see two other options: 1.) `.Range("C3:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value...`; concatenation (already don't like it); if you want to change the first row, you have to do it in two places. 2.) `.Offset(, 1).Value...`; if you want to switch to column `X` or `AX`, do you really want to count how many columns? Simply memorize: `Range("Any2:Any11").EntireRow.Columns("C")` references `Range("C2:C11")`. Keep in mind that this only works with contiguous ranges. Otherwise, you have to use `Intersect`.

Comment: It seems I spoke too soon. Using BYROW within EVALUATE appears to have a limit of 254 rows. Beyond that it returns #VALUE for every row. Is there a way around this limitation? If not, I found that applying my BYROW formulas into the first row of the destination range with `.Range("cell1").Formula2` also achieves what I need.

Comment: Why do you think there would be such a limit? I tested it on `B3:B1048574` and it took about 6s on my machine. You gotta be aware that `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, and several other functions fail if the range contains an error. Of course, you can put an equal sign in front of the formula and write the formula using `.Formula2` to `C3` but you required values only e.g. a `.Evaluate` version.

Comment: Interesting. I tested it on `B3:B212785` and it returned every row as #VALUE. I iteratively reduced the range until I narrowed it down to `B3:B256` where it worked as expected. There are no errors in my data column. Thanks for confirming there is no row limit. Obviously, there is another issue I have to track down. Will report back.

Comment: It is working as expected. I modified the formula to extend the functionality with additional steps, so it takes just under 1.5 minutes to compute 213,000 rows. I am not certain, but I think the VBA editor stops and immediately returns `#VALUE` if I click/scroll inside the editor while it is processing. Once that happens, I have to close and reopen the document to get it to work correctly for anything beyond row 256 again. Apologies, but it was my own impatience causing the problem. Thank you again.